Who are these characters in the "What If...?" season 3 trailer?
I would like to know who these characters in the recently released trailer for What If...? season 3 are. I was not able to identify them.








I think the woman in the first and fourth image in the question is the same person, judging by the purple jewel on her forehead. So I count six characters here and am identifying them as follows...

Character in image 1 (and on the left in image 4): variant of Agatha Harkness.

Agatha's inclusion in the series is confirmed on the Marvel.com page for the What If...? season 3 trailer.


Character on the left in image 2: variant of Kate Bishop.



Character on the right in image 2: variant of Shang-Chi.

Shang-Chi's inclusion in the series is confirmed on the Marvel.com page for the What If...? season 3 trailer. The character in question is also shown using kung fu-esque moves elsewhere in the trailer and the Ten Rings are visible in a scene from what's presumably a different episode involving Avengers mechs. I don't know if there's a connection to What If...? season 3 or not, but it's been reported that Kate Bishop and Shang-Chi will be teaming up alongside other characters in the upcoming Marvel Zombies miniseries. Marvel zombies previously appeared in What If...? S01E05, "What If... Zombies?!."


Character on the left in image 3: variant of Valkyrie.

A variant of Valkyrie previously appeared in What If...? S01E07, "What If... Thor Were an Only Child?."


Character on the right in image 3: variant of Ying Nan.



Character on the right in image 4: variant of Kingo.

The Celestial, Arishem, is shown elsewhere in the trailer, suggesting that the Eternals will be making an appearance.


I wonder if the 'Gunslinger Loki' from What If...? season 2 will appear in the episode with the Wild West versions of Kate Bishop and Shang-Chi.
